# the function display() does not exist

Tags: arduino, processing

I keep getting the error "the function `display()` does not exist. I'm just trying to put my own image in instead of a pre drawn ellipse in processing. Here is my code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import cc.arduino.*;
import com.tinkerkit.*;

Arduino arduino;

//declare the button
TKButton but;
TKButton but1;

{
  arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[2], 57600);
}

PFont myFont;

PImage ball1;

int pScore;  

// don't touch em!

int gameState; //0= pre game 1= in game 2= game over

//setting up perimeter to contain ball character
int width = 600;
int height = 600;

void setup() {
  size(width, height);
  smooth();

  //myFont = loadFont("MyFutura.vlw");
  //textFont(myFont);
  gameState = 0;
  ball1 = loadImage("ball.gif");
  pScore = 0;
}

{
  but = new TKButton(arduino, TK.I0);

  but1 = new TKButton(arduino, TK.I1);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  if (gameState==0) {
    fill(255, 255, 255, 70);
    rect(-10, 30, 370, 70, 7);

    fill(255, 255, 255, 70);
    rect(-10, 120, 330, 50, 7);

    fill(255);
    textSize(60);

    text("Ball Game", 30, 85);
    textSize(40);

    text("Press B to Start", 30, 157);
    if (keyPressed && key == 'b') {
      gameState = 1;
    }

  }

  if (gameState == 2) {
    fill(255, 255, 255, 70);
    rect(-10, 30, 370, 70, 7);

    fill(255, 255, 255, 70);
    rect(-10, 120, 250, 50, 7);
    fill(255, 255, 255, 70);
    rect(-10, 190, 330, 50, 7);

    fill(255);
    textSize(50);
    text("Final Score:", 20, 85);
    text(pScore, 280, 85);

    textSize(30);
    text("Play Again?", 30, 157);
    textSize(30);
    text("Press R to Restart", 30, 225);

    if (keyPressed && key == 'r') {
      gameState = 0;
      setup();
    }

  }

  ball1.display();
  ball1.keyPressed();
}

void display() {
  fill(255);
  noStroke();
}

void reset() {
   ...
}

class ball1 {   
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  float r; //radius
  color c = color(255, 20, 245);  

  ball1(float tempX, float tempY, float tempR) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    r = tempR;
    speed = 0;
  }

  void change() {
    c = color(random(255), random(220), random(245));
  }

  void display() {
    fill (c);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }

  //key commands
  //ball flies off page in response to key command
  void keyPressed() {

    if (key == CODED) {
    }

    if (but.read ()== TK.HIGH) {
      x = x+5;
      if (x >= width - 25) {
        x = width - 25;
      }

      println(but.read());
    } else if (but1.read() == TK.HIGH) {
      x = x-5;
      if (x <= 25) {
        x = 25;
      }

      println(but1.read());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ball1 variable is of type PImage.

The PImage class does not have a display() method.

Maybe your ball1 variable should be inside the ball1 class? If so, rename your class to something sane like Ball (in other words, follow the standard naming conventions and don't use the same name for a class and variable). Then rename your ball1 variable to something sane like ballImage. Then inside your Ball class's display() function, call image(ballImage, x, y) or one of the other image() functions.

Recommended reading:

https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html

https://processing.org/reference/image_.html